# SSH error when trying to deploy to Digital Ocean via Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: node.js, shell, express, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Good Evening,
I am trying to deploy to Digital Ocean via a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline, but when I run the pipeline I get a:
"chmod: /root/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
$ chmod og= ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1".

For some reason its not using the user that I have made for deployment, and is using the root, but when I use the cat command to view the ssh key in my server it shows in both root and deployer user.
The below is my .yml file.

```js
before_script:
  - echo $PATH
  - pwd
  - whoami 
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - cd ~/.ssh
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > id_rsa
  - echo "$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > id_rsa.pub
  - chmod 700 id_rsa id_rsa.pub
  - cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
  - cp id_rsa.pub known_hosts
  - ls -ld *
  - cd -

stages:
  - build
  - publish
  - deploy

variables:
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

build:
  image: node:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - echo   "ACCOUNT_SID=$ACCOUNT_SID" >> .env
    - echo   "AUTH_TOKEN=$AUTH_TOKEN" >> .env
    - echo   "API_KEY=$API_KEY" >> .env
    - echo   "API_SECRET=$API_SECRET" >> .env
    - echo   "PHONE_NUMBER=$PHONE_NUMBER" >> .env
    - echo    "sengrid_api=$sengrid_api" >> .env

publish:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: publish
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build . -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST 
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST

deploy:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - deployment
  script:
    - whoami
    - uname -a
    - echo "user $SERVER_USER"
    - echo "ip $SERVER_IP"
    - echo "id_rsa $ID_RSA"
    - (which ifconfig) || (apt install net-tools)
    - /sbin/ifconfig
    - touch blah
    - find .
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker pull $TAG_COMMIT"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker container rm -f my-app || true"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker run -d -p 80:3000 --name my-app $TAG_COMMIT"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://167.172.225.124
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prerequisites of the [DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-continuous-deployment-pipeline-with-gitlab-ci-cd-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-3-%E2%80%94-creating-a-deployment-user) you are following include a sudo non-root user, and a user account on a GitLab instance with an enabled container registry.

The gitlab-runner service installed through script.deb.sh should need a non-root user’s password to proceed.

And it involves creating a user that is dedicated for the deployment task, with a CI/CD pipeline configured later to log in to the server with that user.

That means the gitlab-ci is not supposed to be executed by `root`, which is not involved at any stage.

Comment: I created a non root user (deployer) and made the gitlab runner. I assigned the server_user variable in gitlab. Should I register the gitlab runner in the none root user? When following the tutorial I registered it in the root user.

Comment: @augdog97 yes, I suspect registering to the root user is the, err..., root cause of this issue.

Comment: I will try and re register to the non root user.

Comment: I have updated the yml file to the above and I have added the public key in Gitlab SSH keys

Comment: Its not a problem, I thank you for all of your help that you have given. If you are up for some more please see the new question. I am trying to get my app to actually run, but docker is having issues.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of work and errors:

cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys: fixed the permission denied (public key,password) error
ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> authorized_keys: This key fixed connection refused error.
The below is the final .yml file that works.

```js
# ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> authorized_keys: use this command to add gitlab ssh keys to sever. Run on server terminal
# cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys Run this command on the sever on the terminal. 
# Both COMMANDS ABOVE ARE necessary.

stages:
  - build
  - publish
  - deploy

variables:
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

build:
  image: node:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - echo   "ACCOUNT_SID=$ACCOUNT_SID" >> .env
    - echo   "AUTH_TOKEN=$AUTH_TOKEN" >> .env
    - echo   "API_KEY=$API_KEY" >> .env
    - echo   "API_SECRET=$API_SECRET" >> .env
    - echo   "PHONE_NUMBER=$PHONE_NUMBER" >> .env
    - echo    "sengrid_api=$sengrid_api" >> .env

publish:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: publish
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build . -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST 
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST

deploy:
  image: ubuntu:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - deployment
  before_script:
    ##
  ## Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
  ## (change apt-get to yum if you use an RPM-based image)
  ##
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client git -y )'

  ##
  ## Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
  ##
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  ##
  ## Create the SSH directory and give it the right permissions
  ##
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  ##
  ## Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
  ## We're using tr to fix line endings which makes ed25519 keys work
  ## without extra base64 encoding.
  ## https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1#note_48526556
  ##
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - echo "$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/*.pub
  - ssh-add
 

  ##
  ## Use ssh-keyscan to scan the keys of your private server. Replace gitlab.com
  ## with your own domain name. You can copy and repeat that command if you have
  ## more than one server to connect to.
  ##
  - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - ls -ld ~/.ssh/*
  - cat ~/.ssh/*
  ##
  ## Alternatively, assuming you created the SSH_SERVER_HOSTKEYS variable
  ## previously, uncomment the following two lines instead.
  ##
  #- echo "$SSH_SERVER_HOSTKEYS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
  #- chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

  ##
  ## You can optionally disable host key checking. Be aware that by adding that
  ## you are suspectible to man-in-the-middle attacks.
  ## WARNING: Use this only with the Docker executor, if you use it with shell
  ## you will overwrite your user's SSH config.
  ##
  #- '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

  ##
  ## Optionally, if you will be using any Git commands, set the user name and
  ## email.
  ##

  script:
    
    - ssh -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker pull $TAG_COMMIT"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker container rm -f my-app || true"
    - ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker run -d -p 80:3000 --name my-app $TAG_COMMIT"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://167.172.225.124
  only:
    - master
```